# From where to get updates?

Tags: feature-request

Suppose, I am using an iphone application. Store within iphone always keep telling me that updates for this & that application are available now.

Similarly, I Found many updates on stack-overflow.

- Like on, April-Fool Day everyone were with new unicorn photos
- Then I found new calender under visits
- Then I found StackExchange quick menu to the top-left.

These were few changes that I observed.
I don't want the brief details on it, But I am a guy who is interested in watching what's new on stackoverflow ? Most of the time, I found new & new features & that sounds cool. isn't there any facility to let you/user know that this is new facility. Like when we switch to new profile view in facebook - it guides us, how it works.

Similarly, What I want to see is - Hey watch out this is new feature in stackover-flow. Click here to know brief.

Please let me know your comments.

Thanks,
Sugar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally anything large gets announced on the blog.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com

Note that in the footer when there is a new blog entry it will appear highlighted with [new] like so:

[image: blog footer highlight]

(and you can mouse over the word "new" to see how old the newest blog entry is, in a tooltip)

Beyond that, if you want minutiae, the community has you covered..

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446)

Comment: @sugar, no, the blog is old, and the link to it too. What's new is that you see 'new' if there's a 'new' post on the blog.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a way to do that - all updates are updated into [this meta-thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), and you can just follow it with [this feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/59445).

However, I agree it's not very visible, maybe the most important updates should be reflected on the main site in a more prominent way. Then again sometimes important updates are mentioned in the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/), which is definitely more visible.